# I can print the result but it doesn't appear on my CSV file after scraping

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am a beginner to python and scraping, so I still have some difficulties to scrape a simple table, which is hosted on this website [http://www.concursopublico.sp.gov.br/PortalConcurso/noauth/PortalDeConcursos.do?acao=concursoEncerrado].

I have been following a tutorial on YouTube [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XQgXKtPSzUI], but since this website seems easier to scrape, the steps don't match with the ones on the video.

For now, my code is able to print the "td" (the content inside the table), but the file "concurso.csv" is empty. I ain't sure what I've done wrong. I appreciate some help.

My question linked by @coldspeed as duplicated doesn't clarify my doubt – it could be other's too. I've already googled a lot about the reason why my script doesn't work. It's unfair to close my question without any reason.

@coldspeed, I ain't even asking about new line or something similar. My doubt is related to content which should be inside the CSV.

```python
# my scrapper following this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XQgXKtPSzUI

import bs4
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

my_url = "http://www.concursopublico.sp.gov.br/PortalConcurso/noauth/PortalDeConcursos.do?acao=concursoEncerrado"
uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()
page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")

td = page_soup.findAll("td")

filename = "concurso.csv"
f = open(filename, "w")

print("td")

f.close()
```

Comment: you have to write in the file.

Comment: Is this python2 or 3?

Comment: it's python 3, @coldspeed

Comment: dear @coldspeed, can you open my question, so I can read the answer written by @ArpitSolanki?

Comment: Why don't you use the [csv lib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#writer-objects)?

Comment: Then you can do something like: `rows = [[td.text for td in tr.find_all('td')] for tr in page_soup.find_all("tr")]` and write `rows` to csv.

Comment: thank you, @t.m.adam! now I have it!

Comment: Yeah, the method in this tutorial is not recommended for writting csv files.

Comment: Also you may want to remove extra spaces: `td.text.strip()` or `td.get_text(strip=True)`